# Creating text pdf with multiple pages of the UITableView data

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print all rows of a table view when it’s too large to fit on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795141/print-all-rows-of-a-table-view-when-its-too-large-to-fit-on-screen)

I need to implement a functionality of creating a text pdf with multiple pages of a view that is having UITableView controller.

I am able to create pdf,but with one page only.

The problem is this: I am unable to break the tableView while rendering it to the pdf-context. I am using the following code to do this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.pdf",documentsDirectory],CGRectMake(0, 0, m_TableView.frame.size.width, m_TableView.frame.size.height), nil);

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
[self.m_TableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

As you can see,I am using `self.m_TableView.layer` for rendering. I can not break the UITableView layer.

Is there any other way with which I can create pdf with multiple pages from a tableview control??

Comment: On what depends the length of the every page?

Comment: The length of each page can be general,A4 size or it can be 612x792 px as default length for pdf pages.