# Print all rows of a table view when it's too large to fit on screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, printing

How do I print my whole multi-page `UITableView` (I need to scroll) and not just the part of the view which is currently displayed on screen?

Comment: You don't scroll to do this, you create a table view large enough for all your elements to be "visible".  Note that this is not a view that you'd display -- it's only internal.  Once you have the view you can convert it to an image and print it.

Comment: (Note to the critics:  user1888996 is attempting to ask a legitimate question (third attempt, in fact), but simply does not know the terminology to use.  It wouldn't hurt folks to be a little more tolerant.)

Comment: Try to be more specific in what you are trying to do with the table, do you want to get an image of if? do you want to get the values for the non visible cells? what's exactly what your doing?

Comment: @user1888996 : This is your third attempt to ask a question. I understand you are trying to ask something which we are not able to understand and help you. We need to understand what exactly you want to know so that we can help you. (Aap 3rd time ek question puchne ki kosish kar rahe ho. Aapko help karne ke liye hum mein aapka question samjhna chahiye.) Print - Taking print out from printer etc etc. Display - only display the UITable view. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: @HotLicks: Perhaps you would consider helping everyone out by editing the question, given that you seem to understand it?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett -- I'd consider that, but the questions are closed too rapidly for me to do it.

Comment: I am in the re-open queue, and the question has not become detailed enough for me to cast a re-open vote.  Try giving us the necessary information.  What is your project, what are you trying to do, relevant code, simple example, etc. and then it might be re-openable

Comment: Yes, user1888996, edit your message with more information and it may be reopened.  In particular make it clear whether you're really talking about "printing" (either to paper or to, eg, a PDF) or just displaying.  And examine Rob Mayoff's answer below and indicate the extent to which is does or doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 15):

I assume you're talking about printing using the iOS printing system, described in [the “Printing” chapter of the *Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/Printing/Printing.html).

Since `-[UITableView viewPrintFormatter]` doesn't return a usable `UIViewPrintFormatter`, you have to find another way to do it.  Let's write a function that turns a table view into a PDF:

```
static NSData *pdfDataWithTableView(UITableView *tableView) {
```

First, we'll save away the view's current bounds, so we can restore the bounds at the end.

```
    CGRect priorBounds = tableView.bounds;
```

Now we'll ask the table view to figure out how tall it needs to be to fit all of its rows.

```
    CGSize fittedSize = [tableView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(priorBounds.size.width, HUGE_VALF)];
```

And we'll go ahead and resize the table view to be that big.  We also set its origin (which is the same as its `contentOffset`) to 0,0 so it will actually contain all of its rows.

```
    tableView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, fittedSize.width, fittedSize.height);
```

We'll need a `CGRect` containing the bounds of our PDF page.

```
    // Standard US Letter dimensions 8.5" x 11"
    CGRect pdfPageBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792);
```

Now we can create a PDF graphics context.

```
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil); {
```

We need to render the table view into the graphics context.  Since the table view may be taller than the page size, we step the origin of the context down the Y axis in increments of the page height.

```
        for (CGFloat pageOriginY = 0; pageOriginY < fittedSize.height; pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height) {
```

We tell the context to begin a page.

```
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil);
```

Since we're going to change the context's origin, we will save the graphics state and restore it after rendering this page.

```
            CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()); {
```

Now we can adjust the origin of the context so that the top-left corner of the rendering area is at the appropriate point in our table view's coordinate system.

```
                CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -pageOriginY);
```

Finally we can tell the table view's layer to render itself to the context.  Everything outside of the current page's bounds will be clipped away.

```
                [tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

To clean up, we restore the graphics state.

```
            } CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
```

At this point, if there are more pages, we'll go back to the top of the `for` loop.

```
        }
```

Now we've rendered all of the pages, so we can end the PDF graphics context.

```
    } UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

And we need to restore the table view's bounds.

```
    tableView.bounds = priorBounds;
```

And finally we can return the PDF data.

```
    return pdfData;
}
```

Here it is all together:

```
static NSData *pdfDataWithTableView(UITableView *tableView) {
    CGRect priorBounds = tableView.bounds;
    CGSize fittedSize = [tableView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(priorBounds.size.width, HUGE_VALF)];
    tableView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, fittedSize.width, fittedSize.height);

    // Standard US Letter dimensions 8.5" x 11"
    CGRect pdfPageBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792);

    NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil); {
        for (CGFloat pageOriginY = 0; pageOriginY < fittedSize.height; pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height) {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil);
            CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()); {
                CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -pageOriginY);
                [tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
            } CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        }
    } UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    tableView.bounds = priorBounds;
    return pdfData;
}
```

You could of course use `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile` instead.  That would use a lot less working memory.

Either way, once you have the PDF (in memory or in a file), you can use the iOS printing system to send it to a printer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not at work where I can look at the projects where we've done this, but your example looks about like what we've done.

Comment: I've tried your code - it's fine to print the visible content of the table view. But assume it has 100 rows, 20 are visible and 25 fit on a page, then I get 20 rows printed. The rest of the first page and page 2 up to the end is blank. The table view cells are reusable, so they don't have any content if they are not visible. Any workaround here?

Comment: @rob mayoff, Thanks so much for a great detailed answer! I used your code to make a PDF of my tableview, but some of the printing gets chopped off near some of the tops and bottoms of the pages.  Any tips?  I tried changing the pdfPageBounds to be a multiple of my cell height, but I still get some clipping of the text. Thanks for your time, and sorry for bugging you.

Comment: in 2020...I have list of 300 items , how can we show them in PDF..all I am able to do is show visible cells in pdf..

Comment: @rob mayoff Its not working in iOS13!

Comment: This is great, I have a view at the top and bottom of tableview , I want convert the all the rows and top and bottom view of the screen to PDF, if table becomes multiple screens,(more than of cells) in all the screens, top and bottom view should come while converting to PDF